# React Native, UIUserNotificationSettings is deprecated for iOS 10.0.

Tags: objective-c, xcode, push-notification, react-native

React Native have made a code snippet on their [website](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html) 
that you can use for handling PushNotificationsIOS. The problem is that, it is now outdated and UIUSerNotificationSettings is deprecated for iOS 10.0.

```
/Users/../ios/project/AppDelegate.m:39:87: 'UIUserNotificationSettings' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationSettings
```

There is a clear suggestion to use [UNNotificationSettings](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationsettings?language=objc), but I am unsure of how to rewrite the given code snippet from React Native to the suggested code, preferably in Objective-C and not Swift.

I have never really worked in Xcode before, so help is appreciated.

Kind regards,

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this link:

[iOS 10 User Notification features](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1143773/ios-user-notification-features)

It should get you going. It's a bit lengthy, but take the time to read it through to understand it.